OOM after files remove with ZFS and deduplication
I’ve encountered a serious issue with my ZFS testbed. When I write a large amount of data (four 2TB files) and then attempt to remove them using the rm command, the RAM usage quickly spikes, causing my test VM to run out of memory. The same issue arises when I delete 8,000 files of 1GB each.
After writing the test files, I noticed that RAM usage stabilizes at around 47GB, even though the ARC is limited to 32GB.
The VM setup includes 32 vCPUs and 64GB of RAM. It has a RAIDZ1 pool with fast deduplication feature enabled, currently running ZFS version 2.3.0 RC2.
I'm reaching out to the community to see if anyone has faced similar issues or might know a workaround.
I've recently posted the issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/16697

Looks like ZFS is trying to load all the metadata into memory at once and just runs out of it fast. The fix would be something like a ‘starving’ algorithm—basically just marking files as ‘deleted’ and returning ‘success’ to the caller, but actually deferring the real unlink job to a background process that can handle the metadata in a safer, more manageable way. This is what the ZFS devs are working on now. You might want to try a private fix to see if it works for you.
https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/16697#issuecomment-2456213252
P.S. Thanks for all your efforts to make ZFS better!
